# What would happen if a muggle went inside hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter

Since muggles know nothing about Hogwarts and the wizards inside don't want any muggles finding it, what would happen if a muggle had discovered it by accident (For example, plane crash or hiking)? What would the wizards do to the muggle?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmzuRXLzqKk